# Use generics to statically type key of record in a self-referential manner

Tags: typescript

The idea is to create a finite state machine helper for my chatbot automation library, so that the people talking to the bot can progress through different phases of a conversation.

I want the consumer of the library to provide a "state machine descriptor" to a function that would instantiate the state machine.

All the behavior is already working. I just want to improve the static typing for the consumers of the library.

This is what I want to accomplish:

```js
const myStateMachine = createStateMachine({
    initialState: "state1",
    states: {
        state1: {
            onMessage: (requester: MessageObj, stateMachine: StateMachineInstance) => {
                requester.reply("hello1");
                stateMachine.setState("state2");
            }
        },
        state2: {
            onMessage: (requester: MessageObj, stateMachine: StateMachineInstance) => {
                requester.reply("hello2");
                stateMachine.setState("state1");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the problem I'm facing: the method `stateMachine.setState("state2")` accepts any string, not just the keys of the states provided in the descriptor. It should accept `"state1" | "state2"` because those are the states that the state machine would have.

I've tried a bunch of different things but most of them result in a typescript error. I just reverted those back to a generic string so that it would compile.

Here is what the types look like at the moment:

```js
type StateId = string;

type State =
    {
        onMessage: (
            requester: MessageObj,
            stateMachineInstance: StateMachineInstance
        ) => any;
    }

type StateMachineDescriptor = {
    initialState: StateId;
    states: {
        [stateId: string]: State,
    }
};

type StateMachineInstance = StateMachineDescriptor & {
    currentState: StateId;
    setState: (newState: StateId) => void;
    reset: () => void;
};
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://tsplay.dev/mbynPN

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you. Now I just need to understand how it works hahahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my entire thought process behind writing a possible solution:

Since we *need* generics to solve this, I'll go ahead and write the signature of the function using one:

```
declare function createStateMachine<States extends string>(value: StateMachineDescriptor<States>): StateMachineInstance<States>;
```

While you *could* probably make it work with `States` being an object type, having it represent the state names is a lot easier to work with. The first problem we encounter is TypeScript inferring `States` from the wrong place. If we write something like this:

```
type StateMachineDescriptor<States extends string> = {
    initialState: States;
    states: Record<States, State<States>>;
};
```

Then TypeScript will infer `States` from `initialState`, which is wrong since we want `initialState` to be based off of `states`, not the other way around.  We can prevent inference on `initialState` using a trick to move it down the list of possible inference sites:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

Blocking inference at `initialState`, it works as intended:

```
type StateMachineDescriptor<States extends string> = {
    initialState: NoInfer<States>;
    states: Record<States, State<States>>;
};
```

That was really the main problem here. Now all we have to do is add in a generic parameter:

```
type StateMachineInstance<States extends string> = StateMachineDescriptor<States> & {
    currentState: States;
    setState: (newState: States) => void;
    reset: () => void;
};

type State<States extends string> =
    {
        onMessage: (
            requester: MessageObj,
            stateMachineInstance: StateMachineInstance<States>
        ) => any;
    }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCB5ARgKygXigG8oAnCMAGxAAoBbBZNALinmBIEsA7FAShYBuAew4ATANxQAvuICwAKAWhIUAMrAkwCAB51mhFAgAPLV1HxW7bigB8+BVEdEHT10K5xEqCC2ovXAaQQAI4ArghaJCyejBg4ADT+gU5s+jBIAMYAFtwQAJJcqVwZPmoaWunZuQVFJbrlCDZJrrz4dkhcIHLyrlIKSuDQehWZOVwQACIIGZxgwEIk9foWxqbmlpw8dgSESdwcwBxIFMOlAHJCBQBmEIun8Dbdrqla8CwAShAZC6JLr-FlfR-RqPBQyfryZRDBqVMb5QoaYo6e6GEwQMwWNibWz4QEjKrjKbwGYcOYLYEPKAAMmcPScGVCJDIXGApxY9yeKQgrIavnGAHc2XiEK08HZhGJOY4yPBub5ReKRBIwd0BioLtdbtoACrbKAAbW1AF1Dai1hYOiAoAB+KAABigLHGAluRtV8lEXwoSDIUCuoWKh3cUBmEH0p1huQpZvR6yx1hs1AEx3C7Jho1yRJJZLuDQe-GFkfGNURdXuoMU8m+CKgtBAEYz41xofD6YJEGouzpjn2h2OQoARC8IABGAeJbuWZYsLvJKdaEcz5rJdwxby+MhhCK3AHDosQBW0udzzfhNi3AB0ZEoNAHWQgFAoQjHvClx+ebbhF9lPP01CHDQAEwDq+y6BH0k69BOc7DoBS6QSuHgMOuUDUKe24kLun65Ies7vgE6HniQV7kFQ-73o+QjAaBCHvnujYQN+3KnP+w4vm+c4QZxSQQVIr5AA)